# Bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

The question results from an idea I got in [the proof of countable union of countable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074587/rigorous-proof-that-countable-union-of-countable-sets-is-countable). As usual, the set of natural numbers is
$\mathbb{N}=\{1, 2, \cdots\}$

So in that case, the question of countable union basically boils down to finding a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^2$. My question is whether it is possible to define a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.