# Show that finite union of countable sets is countable

Tags: real-analysis

The question is: Prove if $A_1, . . . , A_m$ are each countable sets then $A_1∪ · · · ∪ A_m$ is countable.

My attempt: First consider two countable sets $A_1$ and $A_2$. And let $B_2=A_2/A_1$, so $A_1$ and $B_2$ is disjoint. Then $A_1 \cup A_2 = A_1 \cup B_2$. Now since $A_1$ and $B_2$ are countable, $A_1=\left\{a_1, a_2, .. \right\}$ and $B_2=\left\{b_1, b_2, .. \right\}$. Then $A_1 \cup B_2=\left\{ a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, ..\right\}$. Now if we define a function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow  A_1 \cup B_2$ in the following way,

$$ f(n)= \left\{\begin{matrix}
 a_\frac{n+1}{2}& \text{if n is odd} \\
 b_n& \text{ if n is even} \\
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Now we can see that $A_1 \cup B_2= A_1 \cup A_2$ is countable.
Now using induction we can show that $A_1∪ · · · ∪ A_m $ is countable. Suppose $A_1∪ · · · ∪ A_m$ is countable. Then $(A_1∪ · · · ∪ A_m )\cup A_{m+1}$ is countable since we know that the union of two countable set is countable.

Is that the right way to prove it?

Comment: No.  that just shows that a finite union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: The underlying question has been asked many times here...[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603456/prove-that-the-union-of-countably-many-countable-sets-is-countable) is one duplicate. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074587/rigorous-proof-that-countable-union-of-countable-sets-is-countable) is another.

Comment: @lulu but the question didn't ask for infinite union of countable sets?

Comment: Of course it did.  If you wanted all your sets to be finite you should have said finite instead of countable.

Comment: I am referring to the question in the header.  If you meant to ask something else,  please edit for clarity.

Comment: @lulu I have edited it.

Comment: Ok, well, as I said initially, the argument you gave is fine for that case.  Alternatively, you could use the same technique you applied in the case $m=2$.  Just put set $A_i$ in the slots $\equiv i \pmod m$ and alter your function accordingly.

Comment: To simplify it further, you really need to prove that the union of two countable sets is countable. The finite unions, then just follow by induction.